# R regular expression issue

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe column including pages paths :

```
pagePath
/text/other_text/123-some_other_txet-4571/text.html
/text/other_text/another_txet/15-some_other_txet.html
/text/other_text/25189-some_other_txet/45112-text.html
/text/other_text/text/text/5418874-some_other_txet.html
/text/other_text/text/text/some_other_txet-4157/text.html
```

What I want to do is to extract the first number after a `/`, for example `123` from each row.

To solve this problem, I tried the following :

```
 num = gsub("\\D"," ", mydata$pagePath) /*to delete all characters other than digits */

 num1 = gsub("\\s+"," ",num) /*to let only one space between numbers*/

 num2 = gsub("^\\s","",num1) /*to delete the first space in my string*/

 my_number = gsub( " .*$", "", num2 ) /*to select the first number on my string*/
```

I thought that what's that I wanted, but I had some troubles, especially with rows like the last row in the example : `/text/other_text/text/text/some_other_txet-4157/text.html`

So, what I really want is to extract the first number after a `/`.

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: So, you need `123`, `15`, `25189`, `5418874`, `4157`? Use `gsub("^.*?/[^/\\d]*(\\d+).*", "\\1", mydata$pagePath)`

Comment: No @WiktorStribiżew, I need only : `123`, `15`, `25189`, `5418874`

Comment: What about using stringr package? Or do you want a `gsub` based solution (try `> gsub("^(?:.*?/(\\d+))?.*$", "\\1", s)`)?

Comment: Good, I finally figured it out that default `gsub` TRE regex engine does not cope with mixed quantifier types well, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `gsub`:

```
"^(?:.*?/(\\d+))?.*$"
```

And replace with `"\\1"`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW7fV9/2).

Code:

```
> s <- c("/text/other_text/123-some_other_txet-4571/text.html", "/text/other_text/another_txet/15-some_other_txet.html", "/text/other_text/25189-some_other_txet/45112-text.html", "/text/other_text/text/text/5418874-some_other_txet.html", "/text/other_text/text/text/some_other_txet-4157/text.html")
> gsub("^(?:.*?/(\\d+))?.*$", "\\1", s, perl=T)
[1] "123"     "15"      "25189"   "5418874" ""
```

The regex will match optionally (with a `(?:.*?/(\\d+))?` subpattern) a part of string from the beginning till the first `/` (with `.*?/`) followed with 1 or more digits (capturing the digits into Group 1, with `(\\d+)`) and then the rest of the string up to its end (with `.*$`).

NOTE that `perl=T` is required.

with *stringr* `str_extract`, your code and pattern can be shortened to:

```
> str_extract(s, "(?<=/)\\d+")
[1] "123"     "15"      "25189"   "5418874" NA       
>
```

The `str_extract` will extract the first 1 or more digits if they are preceded with a `/` (the `/` itself is not returned as part of the match since it is a *lookbehind* subpattern, a zero width assertion, that does not put the matched text into the result).

Comment: Thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew , this what I wanted.

Comment: Very glad to help. Note that `str_extract` will extract the first 1 or more digits if they are preceded with a `/` (but the `/` is not returned since it is part of a lookbehind, a zero width assertion, that does not put the matched text into the result).

Comment: The two solutions worked for me. But I think that I'll use the `str_extract` function. It's much shortened :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
\/(\d+).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pK4rT2/2)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [26-29] `123`
MATCH 2
1.  [91-93] `15`
MATCH 3
1.  [132-137]   `25189`
MATCH 4
1.  [197-204]   `5418874`
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim007, I really liked the online regex tester. That's new for me :)

Comment: @sarah: Please use regex101.com with caution as `gsub` and most base R functions can be used with PCRE regex patterns via `perl=T` (the PCRE/PHP option on that site), but *stringr*  uses **ICU** regex flavor, and what is working well for PCRE might not work with `str_extract` / `str_match`, etc. However, PCRE and ICU are similar indeed, and simple patterns can be checked there, sure.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much for the clarification :)